# php json_encode without quotes in first and end

Tags: php, android, json

i have a json_encode with special character so i use these code to json encoding that character :

```
   function jsonRemoveUnicodeSequences($struct) {  
  return preg_replace("/\\\\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/e", 'iconv(\'UCS-4LE\',\'UTF-8\',pack(\'V\', hexdec(\'U$1\')))', json_encode($struct)); }
```

but with this code my json have quotation in first and end :

```
"{\"category\":[{\"id\":\"4\",\"title\":\"سشیش\",\"image\":\"یبیسبیس\",\"created_at\":\"2014-11-15 22:58:19\"},{\"id\":\"5\",\"title\":\"بشیبش\",\"image\":\"بشبشبش\",\"created_at\":\"2014-11-15 23:07:19\"}],\"success\":1}"
```

i want to delete just first and end quotation for android method can read this . but i dont know how .